# Indexing does not work with index package

Tags: indexing

I am trying to do indexing with the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{index}
\makeindex
\newindex{aut}{adx}{and}{Name Index}
\begin{document}
Hellow \index[aut]{FiRST}
\printindex[aut]
\end{document}
```

Acccording to documention of the [`index`](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/index/index.pdf) package it should work. But makeindex creates empty `.idx` and `.ind`.

If I run code like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{index}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
 Hellow \index{FiRST}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

It runs. But I need to have user-defined index.

Please help me with it. I've searched for several hours on internet, but without success.

Comment: How about using `imakeidx`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you used `\newindex` with second argument `adx` and third argument `and`, the generated files won't have the default extensions `.idx` and `.ind`; the extensions for the associated files in this case will be `.adx` and `.and`.

With your settings for `\newindex`, you need to process your document (I'll assume it's called `doc.tex`) in the following way: run `pdflatex`, then `makeindex` in the special way:

```
makeindex -o doc.and doc.adx
```

and `pdflatex` once more.

For example, in the next example document, three new indices are defined:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{index}
\makeindex

\newindex{aut}{adx}{and}{Authors}
\newindex{fru}{fdx}{fnd}{Fruits}
\newindex{mam}{mdx}{mnd}{Mammals}


\begin{document}
\index[aut]{Cervantes}
\index[aut]{Shakespeare}
\index[fru]{Orange}
\index[fru]{Pineapple}
\index[mam]{Horse}
\index[mam]{Whale}


\printindex[aut]
\printindex[fru]
\printindex[mam]
\end{document}
```

Processing the doucment (again, let's call it `doc.tex`) using

```
pdflatex doc
makeindex -o doc.and doc.adx
makeindex -o doc.mnd doc.mdx
makeindex -o doc.fnd doc.fdx
pdflatex doc
```

gives the three indices:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Some time ago, **egreg** wrote a nice blog entry regarding building indices. I'm sure you will profit from reading it: [`(Don't) forget to run MakeIndex`](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/dont-forget-to-run-makeindex/). In particular, you can forget the old era of `MakeIndex` and change to modern times using [`imakeidx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx)

Answer (score 9):

egreg knows that people like me are lazy/ignorant while running extra commands ;-) That is why they wrote `imakeidx` that makes use of `--shell-escape` functionality and runs `makeindex/xindy` automatically. Hence one can `(never) forget to run MakeIndex`. Here is an example of it (I believe in learning through examples). Compile it with `pdflatex` (*that's all*, try it by yourself) and you will get your indices (four of them).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=aut,title=Authors,columns=3]  %% Define new index of Authors
\makeindex[name=fru,title=Fruits]  %% Define new index of Fruits
\makeindex[name=mam,title=Mammals]  %% Define new index of Mammals

\begin{document}
Here is some text\index{some thing}.
\index[aut]{Cervantes}
\index[aut]{Shakespeare}
\index[aut]{Shaw}
\index[fru]{Orange}
\index[fru]{Pineapple}
\index[mam]{Horse}
\index[mam]{Whale}

\printindex
\printindex[aut]
\printindex[fru]
\printindex[mam]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]